# How to use function input to order a column in my function [R]

Tags: r

I have spent a lot of time on getting the syntax down without success, now something I put away that I am revisiting is that class of my object 
is not just data.frame, I read it in using read_csv{readr} (and my hunch is this could be important.

```
 class(tt)
[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
```

Below is the original post:

---

Its easier to show what I mean.  Note: I can get the if statement to work, now I want to sort the column heart attack.

```
test <- function(state,output) {
        if  ((state %in% unique(tt$State)) & 
             (output %in% names(tt)[3:5])){

                tt2 <- subset(tt, tt$State==state)

                #tt3 <- tt2[order(tt2$output),]
                #tt3$`Hospital Name`[1]

                 print(head(tt2))
        }

        else print("yenoo")
}
```

And some output:

```
> test("AL","Heart Attack")
# A tibble: 6 × 5
                   `Hospital Name` State `Heart Attack` `Heart Failure` Pneumonia
                             <chr> <chr>          <dbl>           <dbl>     <dbl>
1 SOUTHEAST ALABAMA MEDICAL CENTER    AL           14.3            11.4      10.9
2    MARSHALL MEDICAL CENTER SOUTH    AL           18.5            15.2      13.9
3   ELIZA COFFEE MEMORIAL HOSPITAL    AL           18.1            11.3      13.4
4         MIZELL MEMORIAL HOSPITAL    AL             NA            13.6      14.9
5      CRENSHAW COMMUNITY HOSPITAL    AL             NA            13.8      15.8
6    MARSHALL MEDICAL CENTER NORTH    AL             NA            12.5       8.7
```

Now I am struggling to give the if condition an expression (head(tt2) is just a test to see if the if condition is working) that will sort and give the hospital name for the the row with lowest `Heart Attack`.

I can do it outside the function like this:

```
> tt2 <- subset(tt, tt$State=="TX")
> tt3 <- tt2[order(tt2$`Heart Attack`),]
> tt3$`Hospital Name`[1]
[1] "CYPRESS FAIRBANKS MEDICAL CENTER"
```

I been going at this for a moment and might not make sense.  Need a break.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: try this way :order(tt2[output]). if output passed as "Heart Attack" while calling the funciton

Comment: Probably a top 5 mistake in R. The operator `$` is only for convenience, not functional programming.

Comment: Thanks. That was one of the things going through my mind, now I know for sure.  And advice on what topics to review for alternatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeap as I mentioned while editing using {readr} function read_csv the returned object was not data.frame but

```
class(tt)
[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
```

Now there is more to this and I need to fix all the kinks but for now:
Introducing this

```
tt<-as.data.frame(tt)
```

combined with

```
tt3 <- tt2[order(tt2[output]),]
```

allows me to do something, as illustrated with the following call:

```
test("TX","Heart Failure")
[1] "FORT DUNCAN MEDICAL CENTER"
```

My function and code is not very good but will do for now (included for completeness)

```
# The function reads the outcome-of-care-measures.csv file and returns a character vector
# with the name of the hospital that has the best (i.e. lowest) 30-day mortality for the specified outcome
# in that state.

tt <- read_csv("outcome-of-care-measures.csv", col_types = cols_only(`Hospital 30-Day Death (Mortality) Rates from Heart Attack`= col_double(),`Hospital 30-Day Death (Mortality) Rates from Heart Failure`= col_double(),`Hospital 30-Day Death (Mortality) Rates from Pneumonia`= col_double(),`State`=col_character(),`Hospital Name`=col_character()))


names(tt)[3:5] <- c("Heart Attack","Heart Failure", "Pneumonia")


tt<-as.data.frame(tt)

# First test if in input is valid
test <- function(state,output) {
        if  ((state %in% unique(tt$State)) & 
             (output %in% names(tt)[3:5])){

                tt2 <- subset(tt, tt$State==state)

                tt3 <- tt2[order(tt2[output]),]

                tt3$`Hospital Name`[1]


        }  else print("Input error; use 2 letter State Abbrevation, and Heart Attack, Heart Failure, or Pneumonia as outcome")

}
```